# C program crashes when reallocating memory a third time

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic-arrays

I am learning SDL2 to make a simple game in c. I made some code to store entities in one array so I can loop over them to render and move them. Whenever I press R, it's supposed to shoot a bullet. It does it one time, if I press R a second time the window closes. Here is the code:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    int w;
    int h;
    int up;
    int down;
    int left;
    int right;
    SDL_Texture *texture;
} Entity;

typedef struct {
    Entity *entities;
    int size;
    int cap;
} EntityArray;
```

EntityArray entityArr;

```
void addEntity(Entity *entity)
{
    printf("Inside moveEntity function\n");
    printf("The tmp pointer is %d bytes\n", (entityArr.size+1)*sizeof(entityArr.entities));
    Entity *tmp = (Entity*)realloc(entityArr.entities,(entityArr.size+1)*sizeof(entityArr.entities)); // crashes here whenever I allocate more than 16 bytes
    if(!tmp)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory for entity in array");
        free(tmp);
        return;
    }
    entityArr.entities = realloc(entityArr.entities, (entityArr.size+1)*sizeof(entityArr.entities));
    entityArr.size++;
    //memcpy((entityArr.entities+(entityArr.size-1)), entity, sizeof(Entity));
    (*(entityArr.entities+(entityArr.size-1))) = (*entity);
    printf("The entity %d has been added to the array!\n", entityArr.size);
}
```

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    memset(&app, 0, sizeof(App));
    memset(&player, 0, sizeof(Entity));
    //memset(&entityArr, 0, sizeof(EntityArray));

    entityArr.entities = calloc(1, sizeof(Entity*)); 
    entityArr.size = 0;
    entityArr.cap = 0;

    initSDL();

    player.x = 100;
    player.y = 100;
    player.w = 64;
    player.h = 64;
    player.texture = loadTexture("assets/textures/player.png");

    printf("Player entity initialized at address: %p\n", &player);
    
    bullet.x = player.x;
    bullet.y = player.y;
    bullet.w = 16;
    bullet.h = 16;
    bullet.up = 1;
    bullet.texture = loadTexture("assets/textures/bullet.png");
    if(bullet.texture)
    {
        printf("The bullet texture has been defined\n");
    } else {
        printf("The bullet texture has not been defined\n");
    }

    addEntity(&player);


    atexit(cleanUp);

    while (1)
    {
        prepareScene();

        doInput();

        moveEntity(&entityArr.entities);

        blitEntity(entityArr.entities);

        presentScene();

        SDL_Delay(16);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I try to reallocate more than 16 bytes, it crashes

I tried playing around with the memory functions but at this point I am exhausted and do not know what I am doing

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: `(entityArr.size+1)*sizeof(entityArr.entities)` is multiplying by the size of a pointer, not the size of the object that is being pointed at (as you intend.) Put a `*` inside those parentheses and all will be well...

Comment: Also, your first realloc assigning to tmp frees the original memory. The second reealloc tries to free that again. Try using the right size (`(entityArr.size+1)*sizeof(Entity)` just once.

Comment: Btw, what s `entityArr` ? We only see the declaration of `EntityArray`? Please post code that compiles if you want debugging help.

Comment: You've realloaced twice, replace the second one with `entityArr.entities = tmp;`. And better as `Entity *tmp = realloc(... , (entityArr.size+1)*sizeof *tmp);`

Comment: OT: `entityArr.entities = calloc(1, sizeof(Entity*));` would be better entityArr.entities = NULL;` (if it's not already global and NULL by default.) PS: Don't cast the return value of `realloc()`

Answer (score 2):

Once you  have the new memory block in tmp, you need to just assign it to the entities field. There is no need to do a 2nd reallocation after the first was successful. And in fact the 2nd reallocate now occurs on the same pointer which was freed as part of the 1st reallocate operation so this 2nd reallocation is erroneous. Also you need to fix the size that you are allocating.

```
void addEntity(Entity *entity)
{
    printf("Inside moveEntity function\n");
    printf("The tmp pointer is %d bytes\n", (entityArr.size+1)*sizeof(Entity));
    Entity *tmp = (Entity*)realloc(entityArr.entities,(entityArr.size+1)*sizeof(Entity)); // crashes here whenever I allocate more than 16 bytes
    if(!tmp)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory for entity in array");
        free(tmp);
        return;
    }
    entityArr.entities = tmp;
    entityArr.size++;
    //memcpy((entityArr.entities+(entityArr.size-1)), entity, sizeof(Entity));
    (*(entityArr.entities+(entityArr.size-1))) = (*entity);
    printf("The entity %d has been added to the array!\n", entityArr.size);
}
```

Comment: On the first reallocation, the pointer at entityArr.entities is freed. Then when they call the 2nd realloc on it, this is now a bad input and causes the bad behavior when it is passed to the 2nd realloc.

Comment: Just looked closer at the OP code. You're correct on the point that the OP should just use `tmp` as you've shown. My mistake. However, the parameter specifying the size of the block wanted is incorrect, both in the OP code and in this answer... Please fix that... AND, in C, casting the returned pointer is not necessary (and could lead to a bug when modifications are made.)

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Better... Still _casting_ the return from `malloc()`... And, a good answer would point out the uselessness of the `free(tmp);`... Maybe even rearrange the last few lines so that the increment FOLLOWS the assignment (no need for `-1`... Getting there.... slowly... (These are not problems with your code. These are simple good vs bad code.)